# How to create and activate specific Conda Environment on Dataproc with Jupyter Notebook Initialised

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-cloud-dataproc

Once you have the Jupyter notebook installed using the [Google Initialisation script](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/tutorials/jupyter-notebook) is it possible to create and activate a conda environment on all the worker nodes?

Do I need to ssh onto each worker and create the same environment or is there a way to accomplish the same via a notebook if the number of modules to add is small?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a cluster up, there is not a great way to re-configure all workers.

If you create a new cluster the [conda initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/conda) might be helpful.